# Explain the fallacy: Remainder in polynomial division

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I encountered this equation in a problem that I am trying to solve:

$$N= \frac{2*p-x^{2}-x}{2x+2}$$-

Here p and x are Whole numbers (positive integers).

Now I am trying to find all x and p for which 
 N is also a whole number.

I understand that if `z=x/y` is to be a whole number then Reminder(x÷y) should be zero.

I apply this logic and I find that remainder for the above polynomial devision is coming out to be 2p.

I divide $${2*p-x^{2}-x}$$   by    $${2x+2}$$

And the remainder comes out to be $$2p$$

Now since for the N to be whole number remainder should be zero

2p=0 , which means p=0.
If I substitute this above expression:

$$N=\frac{2*0-x^{2}-x}{2x+2}$$

Or
$$N=\frac{-x^{2}-x}{2x+2}$$
And finally,

$$N=\frac{-x}{2}$$

I am confused. For every x , using this result my N is coming out to be a negative integer.

If I simply put , x=1 and p=3 in the first expression I get:

$$N=\frac{2*3-1^{2}-1}{2*1+2}$$

$$N=\frac{6-2}{4}$$

Or 
$$N=\frac{4}{4}$$

N=1.

But with my result :

$$N=\frac{-x}{2}$$

$$N=\frac{-1}{2}$$

So where is the fallacy?

Kindly help me understand.

Thanks

Comment: The quotient doesn’t necessarily have to be a whole number even if the remainder is zero.

Comment: Kindly give an example.

Comment: I think @gpuguy you should give the example yourself.

Comment: Actually, the question already has given an example.

Comment: 16÷8 ,. the remainder is Zero, and quotient is whole number 2.

Answer (score 1):

Polynomial long division and integer long division have different purposes.

In integer long division everything has to come out to an integer,
but we are only concerned with four numerical values:
the two inputs of the division, and the two outputs.

In polynomial long division the inputs and outputs are polynomials, not integers.
Even the coefficients of the polynomials do not need to be integers.
But if we start with two polynomials over $x,$ we get an equation in polynomials that needs to be true for all values of $x,$ not just for four particular numbers.
That is, the equation will be true for a lot of different sets of four numbers,
most of which will not be integers. Since the coefficients of the polynomial quotient and remainder are not guaranteed to be integers, it is not guaranteed that the resulting numerical values are integers even if $x$ is an integer.

The remainder in the polynomial division is $2p$ because

$$ 2p - x^2 - x = \left(\frac12 x\right) (2x+2) + 2p. $$

So if $2p = 0$ then $\dfrac 12 x$ is the ratio $\dfrac{2p - x^2 - x}{2x+2}$,
that is, $N = \dfrac12 x.$ Clearly, setting $x$ to an integer value does not guarantee that $N$ is an integer.
That is not the purpose of polynomial long division.

On the other hand, for some even integer $x$ and some integer $p \neq 0$ it might be the case that $2x+2$ divides $2p,$ in which case
$\dfrac{2p - x^2 - x}{2x+2}$
is an integer.
So the conclusion that $p$ must be zero is false.

Comment: Thank you David. It makes a lot of sense!